# Get all HTML tags with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a list of all html tags from beautiful soup.

I see find all but I have to know the name of the tag before I search.

If there is text like

```
html = """<div>something</div>
<div>something else</div>
<div class='magical'>hi there</div>
<p>ok</p>"""
```

How would I get a list like

```
list_of_tags = ["<div>", "<div>", "<div class='magical'>", "<p>"]
```

I know how to do this with regex, but am trying to learn BS4

Comment: If you want the tags without their children, see [Printing only outer tags in HTML code using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752590/printing-only-outer-tags-in-html-code-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You don't have to specify any arguments to `find_all()` - in this case, `BeautifulSoup` would find you every tag in the tree, recursively.

Sample:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div>something</div>
<div>something else</div>
<div class='magical'>hi there</div>
<p>ok</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print([tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()])
# ['div', 'div', 'div', 'p']

print([str(tag) for tag in soup.find_all()])
# ['<div>something</div>', '<div>something else</div>', '<div class="magical">hi there</div>', '<p>ok</p>']
```

Answer (score 7):

Please try the below--

```
for tag in soup.findAll(True):
    print(tag.name)
```

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd share my solution to a very similar question for those that find themselves here, later.

#### Example

I needed to find all tags quickly but only wanted unique values. I'll use the Python `calendar` module to demonstrate.

We'll generate an html calendar then parse it, finding all and only those unique tags present.

The below structure is *very* similar to the above, using set comprehensions:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import calendar

html_cal = calendar.HTMLCalendar().formatmonth(2020, 1)
set(tag.name for tag in BeautifulSoup(html_cal, 'html.parser').find_all())

# Result
# {'table', 'td', 'th', 'tr'}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find some specific HTML tags then try this:

```py
html = driver.page_source
# driver.page_source: "<div>something</div>\n<div>something else</div>\n<div class='magical'>hi there</div>\n<p>ok</p>\n"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for tag in soup.find_all(['a','div']):  # Mention HTML tag names here.
    print(tag.text)

# Result:
# something
# something else
# hi there
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient function that I use to parse different HTML and text documents:

```
def parse_docs(path, format, tags):
    """
    Parse the different files in path, having html or txt format, and extract the text content.
    Returns a list of strings, where every string is a text document content.
    :param path: str
    :param format: str
    :param tags: list
    :return: list
    """

    docs = []
    if format == "html":
        for document in tqdm(get_list_of_files(path)):
            # print(document)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(open(document, encoding='utf-8').read())
            text = '\n'.join([''.join(s.findAll(text=True)) for s in
                              soup.findAll(tags)])  # parse all <p>, <div>, and <h> tags
            docs.append(text)
    else:
        for document in tqdm(get_list_of_files(path)):
            text = open(document, encoding='utf-8').read()
            docs.append(text)
    return docs
```

a simple call: `parse_docs('/path/to/folder', 'html', ['p', 'h', 'div'])` will return a list of text strings.