# HTML structure into network graph

Tags: python, dom, graph, beautifulsoup, networkx

What I'm trying to do is to represent an HTML site DOM (document object model) into a network graph, and then do some statistical computing with this graph (like degree, betweenness, proximity, plotting of course, etc.). I couldn't find any Library or previous SO post that does it directly. My idea was to use `BeautifulSoup` Library, then `Networkx` Library. I tried to write some code looping through each element of the HTML structure (using `recursive=True`). But I Don't know how to identify each unique tag (you see here that adding a second `h1` node into the graph overwrites the first one, same for parents, so the graph is completely false in the end).

```
import networkx as nx
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ex0 = "<html><head><title>Are you lost ?</title></head><body><h1>Lost on the Intenet ?</h1><h1>Don't panic, we will help you</h1><strong><pre>    * <----- you are here</pre></strong></body></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(ex0)
G=nx.Graph()
for tag in soup.findAll(recursive=True):
    G.add_node(tag.name)
    G.add_edge(tag.name, tag.findParent().name)
nx.draw(G)   
G.nodes
#### NodeView(('html', '[document]', 'head', 'title', 'body', 'h1', 'strong', 'pre'))
```

[image]

Any idea on how it could be done (including completely different approaches). Thanks

PS: the graph could be directed or not, I don't care.

Comment: You've to loop all nested elements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108621/get-all-html-tags-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: @PedroLobito thanks, i'm doing it already, but my problem is about uniqueness of tags or even tag values

Comment: You can use a dictionary to store each tag with a unique key, i.e.: `{'div1', element1, 'div2': element2}`

Comment: Yes, that could be nice, but I have no idea how to implement that into my code :-). And Beautifulsoup will only accept standard tags, not tags with some identifing number in their names...

Comment: I understand, but I also don't have the time to develop a custom answer for you. GL!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can loop over the `content` attribute of each `BeautifulSoup` object. To display the labels, simply utilize the `with_labels` attribute in `nx.draw`:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
ex0 = "<html><head><title>Are you lost ?</title></head><body><h1>Lost on the Intenet ?</h1><h1>Don't panic, we will help you</h1><strong><pre>    * <----- you are here</pre></strong></body></html>"
d = soup(ex0, 'html.parser')
def _traverse_html(_d:soup, _graph:nx.Graph, _counter, _parent=None) -> None:
  for i in _d.contents:
     if i.name is not None:
       try:
         _name_count = _counter.get(i.name)
         if _parent is not None:
           _graph.add_node(_parent)
           _graph.add_edge(_parent, i.name if not _name_count else f'{i.name}_{_name_count}')
         _counter[i.name] += 1
         _traverse_html(i, _graph, _counter, i.name)
       except AttributeError:
         pass

_full_graph = nx.Graph()
_traverse_html(d, _full_graph, defaultdict(int))
nx.draw(_full_graph, with_labels = True)   
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this extensive answer. Still, the output graph is not supposed to have loops, because I want each element to be unique, that's my main problem. For instance, in your first graph, there should be a second node `h1` connected to `body`. How can we do this?

Comment: @agenis Thank you for your comment. I, too, just noticed that `networkx` does not appear to display duplicate nodes. Thus, I utilized a counter for each `name` element and provided an "underscore" on successive nodes with the same name.

Comment: thanks that's what i needed Indeed. I still have to understand your syntax which is a little "Advanced" for me :-)

Comment: @agenis Each `bs4` object has an attribute `contents`, which stores all the child tags of the object (the parent). The recursive function loops over each child of the object passed to it, creates the node and edge, and then calls itself again on each child. However, if an element in `bs4.contents` is not another `bs4` object, an `AttributeError` will be raised (it is the text between tags). The `try/except` block catches the latter error.

Comment: THanks, that's clever Indeed. One last thing, what's with the `-> none:` i Don't know this syntax

Comment: @agenis That is an `annotation`, along with `_d:soup, _graph:nx.Graph`. It is documentation of sorts to specify the desired parameter types.