# BeautifulSoup get all tags of strings

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am a BeautifulSoup newbie and I want to know if there is any way to get the tags by string. Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = s = "<blockquote><i><b>Quote</b></i></blockquote><br />SOME DESIRED TEXT <h3><i>This is a title</i></h3>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
soup_all =  soup.findAll()
for s in soup.strings:
    print get_tags_by_string(s)
```

And get the output of `get_tags_by_string`:

```
Quote -> blockquote
Quote -> i
Quote -> b
SOME DESIRED TEXT  -> Plain
This is a title -> h3
This is a title -> i
```

I am looking the official doc but it seems there is no fucntionality for this.

Thank you in advance!!

**EDIT:**

I've explored this workaround but inner tags are not detected...

```
import bs4
s = "<blockquote><i>Quote</i></blockquote><br />text <h3>This is a title</h3>"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
soup_all = soup.find_all()
for asds in soup.contents:
    if isinstance(asds, bs4.element.Tag) and asds.text != "":
        print "%s -> %s" % (asds.text, asds.name)
    elif isinstance(asds, bs4.element.NavigableString):
        print "%s -> None" % asds
```

Output:

```
Quote -> blockquote
text  -> None
This is a title -> h3
```

**UPDATE:**

This solution works for me:

```
for content in soup.contents:
    if isinstance(content, bs4.element.Tag) and content.text != "":
        print "%s -> %s" % (content.text, content.name)
        # Nested tags
        nested_tags = content.find_all()
        for nested_tag in nested_tags:
            print "%s -> %s" % (nested_tag.text, nested_tag.name)
    elif isinstance(content, bs4.element.NavigableString):
        print "%s -> None" % content
```

Output:

```
Quote -> blockquote
Quote -> i
Quote -> b
SOME DESIRED TEXT  -> Plain
This is a title -> h3
This is a title -> i
```

What do you think about this workaround? Could be valid?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE 2:**

This workaround is not valid for inner nested tags....

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108621/get-all-html-tags-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: That question only gets all tags, but I want to link the text with all its possible tags in someway... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I edited the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = "<blockquote><i>Quote</i></blockquote><br />text <h3>This is a title</h3>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all():
    print("%s -> %s" % (tag.text, tag.name))
```

output:

```
Quote -> blockquote
Quote -> i
 -> br
This is a title -> h3
```

note: br gets also detected as a tag. If you want to avoid printing br tags, you can add an if statement before your print like this:

```
for tag in soup.find_all():
    if tag.text != "":
         print("%s -> %s" % (tag.text, tag.name))
```

Comment: yes, I got this workaround too, but this approach does not identify the 'text' string value, so it is not valid to me... :/

Comment: What 'text' string value do you mean? It generates the expected output. it prints all tags and the text inside them

Comment: if you look closely, you will see a 'SOME TEXT DESIRED' that is not processed that way

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you may be looking for:

```
for tag in soup.find_all():
   if tag.next_sibling:
       if isinstance(tag.next_sibling, bs4.element.Tag):
           print("%s -> %s" % (tag.text,tag.name))
       else:
           print("%s -> %s" % (tag.next_sibling,tag.name))
   else:
           print("%s -> %s" % (tag.text,tag.name))
```

Output:

```
Quote -> blockquote
Quote -> i
Quote -> b
SOME DESIRED TEXT  -> br
This is a title -> h3
This is a title -> i
```