# Printing only outer tags in HTML code using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Part of whole HTML code looks as follows

```
<td class="col2">
<a class="reserve" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"     
href="example.com" rel="nofollow"></a></td>
```

I found it using

```
soup.find_all('td', class_='col2')
```

However I would like to extract not the whole part of the code but only

```
<td class="col2"></td>
```

Is it possible using BeautifulSoup? I know I can do it using strings but I'm just curious.

Comment: The `a` tag is inside `td`. What's your eventual goal?

Answer (score 4):

You could set the `string` attribute to an empty string (`''`):

```
html = """
<td class="col2">
<a class="reserve" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"     
href="example.com" rel="nofollow"></a></td>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
x = soup.find('td', class_='col2')
x.string = ''
print(x)
```

**Output**

```html
<td class="col2"></td>
```

Here is what [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string) tells about it:

> *If you set a tag's `.string` attribute, the tag's contents are replaced with the string you give*

> *Be careful: if the tag contained other tags, they and all their contents will be destroyed.*

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all elements inside `td.col2` with `extract()` function:

```
data = '''
<td class="col2">
<a class="reserve" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"
href="example.com" rel="nofollow"></a></td>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for td in soup.select('td.col2'):
    for t in td.select('*'):
        t.extract()
    print(td)
```

Prints:

```
<td class="col2">
</td>
```