# how to crawl through html string content (tag by tag) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, html-parser

I have html string and would like to find the text elements and replace with the tokens. I used beautifulsoup to get the data but get_text is giving only text not corresponding elements. How to go thorugh html string from root node to last node and finding out the text elements to replace with the tokens I define.
I get dynamic large html string from source. small example has been given

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>

To
----
<html>
<body>
<p>Token1</p>
<p>Token2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108621/get-all-html-tags-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all HTML tags with Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108621/get-all-html-tags-with-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
subst = """
<html>
<body>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
tokens = ['Token1','Token2']
soup = bs(subst, 'lxml')
targets = soup.find_all('p')
for target in targets:
    loc=targets.index(target)
    target.string.replace_with(tokens[loc])    
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Token1</p>
<p>Token2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The html string is dynamic meaning it's not always contains p tags. Code should go through all tags and find text elements and gets updated with the tokens I have

Comment: @BobbyNagendra - You should have made this clear in your question and have an html string that is representative of the actual one. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question