# How to select all tags <b> HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

From this [webpage](http://lib.ru/GrepSearch?search=%E3%E5%F0%EE%E9+%ED%E0%F8%E5%E3%EE+%E2%F0%E5%EC%E5%ED%E8) I need to select all tags `<b> </b>` with `BeautifulSoup4`.

```py
url = "http://lib.ru/GrepSearch?Search=%E3%E5%F0%EE%E9+%ED%E0%F8%E5%E3%EE+%E2%F0%E5%EC%E5%ED%E8"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
author = soup.select('b')
print(author)
```

I have tried using `find_all()` and `select()` but they fail to show all `<b>` tags when used in the array

Comment: Could you provide a [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please. Would be great and helps everyone to understand. Thanks

Comment: Might be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108621/get-all-html-tags-with-beautiful-soup. You may need to tweak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different parsers used in parsing a html document, the most used one is 'html.parser'. I have used lxml here which uses both xml and html to parse through a document.
This code here should give you the raw output you have asked for(Author and Book name). You still have to process it to get your desired output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

requests = requests.get('http://lib.ru/GrepSearch?Search=history')

src = requests.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src , 'lxml')

b_tags = soup.find_all('b')

for b in b_tags:
    print(b.text)
```

Output is like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily a parser issue but anyway, this example should give you author and name of book that initially were requested:

**Example**

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://lib.ru/GrepSearch?Search=%E3%E5%F0%EE%E9+%ED%E0%F8%E5%E3%EE+%E2%F0%E5%EC%E5%ED%E8"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

[{"author":bTag.find_next('b').text, "name": bTag.find_next('ul').text.strip()} for bTag in soup.find_all(string='[dir] ')]
```

**Output**

```
[{'author': 'Джойс Кэри', 'name': 'Герой нашего времени'},
 {'author': 'Михаил Юрьевич Лермонтов', 'name': 'Герой нашего времени'},
 {'author': 'Владимир Маканин',
  'name': 'Андеграунд, или Герой нашего времени'}]
```